# What is the correct way to include OpenCV library in a Qt project using cmake?

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, qt5

I'm having a problem linking my OpenCV library to my project (cmake), I'm using Qt creator (I'm a beginner, just a month) and for almost a week I've been reading about it but I don't understand and it doesn't work not. My opencv folder is in my project directory (Face). Thanks in advance for your answers.
here is my code:

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Face VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick Sql)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Multimedia)

qt_add_executable(appFace
    main.cpp

)
find_library(myopencv libopencv_java4.so
    PATHS
    "C:\\Users\\Hapi\\Documents\\Face\\OpenCV-android-sdk"
    PATH_SUFFIXES
    "sdk\\native\\libs\\armeabi-v7a"
    DOC
    "opencv lib")
if(${myopencv} STREQUAL myopencv-NOTFOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV not found")
else()
    message(STATUS "opencv found!")
endif()
```

the error:
OpenCV not found

[image: error image]

Comment: Have you considered creating a cmake project that only uses opencv? I think qmake will generate it's own cmake files which can be a bit confusing, you might want to learn how to add opencv to a qt project, then generate a cmake project from that. Otherwise you'll generate a cmake project and edit it to include opencv.